# SQL pivot - cross tab and multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

I've got 2 crosstab queries that both work, but I'd like to combine them together.

The first shows the total time that various vehicles were used for at each base:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Cdbl(Nz(M.dtTripTime, 0))) AS SheetTime

SELECT M.lngVehicleID
    ,Sum(Cdbl(Nz(M.dtTripTime, 0))) AS Total
FROM tblSheets M
INNER JOIN Bases B ON M.lngBaseID = B.BaseID
GROUP BY M.lngVehicleID
PIVOT B.BaseName IN (
        'Alpha'
        ,'Bravo'
        ,'Charlie'
        );
```

The second shows the number of trips that each vehicle did at various bases:

```
TRANSFORM Count(M.lngSheetID) AS SheetCount

SELECT M.lngVehicleID
    ,Sum(Cdbl(Nz(M.dtTripTime, 0))) AS Total
FROM tblSheets M
INNER JOIN Bases B ON M.lngBaseID = B.BaseID
GROUP BY M.lngVehicleID
PIVOT B.BaseName IN (
        'Alpha'
        ,'Bravo'
        ,'Charlie'
        );
```

What I'd ideally like is to generate one crosstab that shows both the combined time and the number of trips for each vehicle at the various bases. Is this possible? The above queries maxed out my very limited abilities on SQL!

Comment: What flavor of sql are you working in?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - I'm working within Access 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access, a crosstab allows only one value, one column variable and several row variables, but you could make a third query based on the two you have above, keying on `lngVehicleID`, along the lines of the following--anything else I think would require a VBA solution, but is rather unnecessary.

I assume your crosstabs are saved, named, respectively, and inspiredly, `crosstab1` and `crosstab2`.

[not tested]

```
Select * from crosstab1
inner join crosstab2 on crosstab1.lngVehicleID=crosstab1.lngVehicleID
order by crosstab1.lngVehicleID
```